# Parse file and and get the value of a specific line using Powershell

Tags: json, azure, powershell, cloud

I have a script that run on a list of azure VMs within a subscription and outputs a file for each VM, here is an example of its content:

```
Value[0]        : 
  Code          : ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded
  Level         : Info
  DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
  Message       :     Directory: C:\variasuit_windows\HARMOR\windows_server\package


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
d-----       12/23/2023   5:10 AM                HARMOR                                                                
"Server Name","GPO_HARMOR","BIOMEDIC_AGENT","EDWARD_STATUS","SENSOR_STATUS","SENTINEL_STATUS"
"AZ-TSTAPP1D","OK","OK","OK","OK","KO"


Value[1]        : 
  Code          : ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded
  Level         : Info
  DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
  Message       : 
Status          : Succeeded
Capacity        : 0
Count           : 0
```

I would like to parse the file using powershell to get the this line:

```
"AZ-TSTAPP1D","OK","OK","OK","OK","KO"
```

Then gathering this value from each file to another txt file to have something like this

```
"AZ-TSTAPP1D","OK","OK","OK","OK","KO"
"AZ-TSTAPP2D","OK","KO","KO","KO","KO"
"AZ-TSTAPP3D","OK","OK","OK","OK","KO"
```

I tried to get the content of this specific line but I found out that line number can change from a file to another
I tried this:

```
        $scriptResult = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -VMName $vm.Name -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $scriptPath

        $scriptResult | Out-File $tempFile
        $contentFromFile = Get-Content -Path $tempFile
        $line12 = $contentFromFile | Select-Object -Index 11
        $line12 | Out-File $outputFile -Append
        Remove-Item $tempFile
```

Any help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a general note:

- I don't know if `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` is capable of relaying (serialized) objects, but if, so, you'd be better off operating on objects rather than on their *for-display string representations*.

As for your code:

- You don't need a temporary file and can use [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) with the `-Stream` parameter to get the for-display formatted representations line-by-line; if `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` only emits *text* anyway, you don't even need that.
- You can use the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator with a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) to filter out the line of interest.
- You can use the `>>` [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) operator as a shortcut to piping to [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) `-Append`.

```bash
@($scriptResult | Out-String -Stream) -match '^"AZ-TSTAPP' >> $outputFile
```

The above regex turned out not to be specific enough; per your comment, this is the regex you came up with that worked for you:

```bash
@($scriptResult | Out-String -Stream) -match '^".*AZ-.*",".*",".*",".*"$' >> $outputFile
```

Comment: I tried this regex and it worked :)
@($scriptResult | Out-String -Stream) -match '^".*AZ-.*",".*",".*",".*"$' >> $outputFile
Thanks mate!